# Get all Preferences from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my Android application I have a `PreferenceFragment` which is build from a XML resource file. After the XML is loaded I would like to call a method for each `Preference` in the Fragment. My problem is that I haven't found a method which gives me all Preferences from the current `PreferenceFragment`.

I know that I can find a preference with the `findPreference(...)` method but I would like to get an iterator of all Preferences. Have a missed a method or aren't we able to get all Preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a method to do this with the code below:

```
PreferenceScreen prefScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
int prefCount = prefScreen.getPreferenceCount();

for(int i=0; i < prefCount; i++) {
    Preference pref = prefScreen.getPreference(i);
    // do something with the Preference
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, if your preference screen has categories, you need to loop through each preference's descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `this` is your `PreferenceFragment`, you can call:

```
this.getPreferenceManager().getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getAll();
```

This will return a map with all preferences https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()

Comment: This gives me all preferenceNames as String (not `Preference` objects) and not only the `Preferences` from the current `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version & Take care the `PreferenceCategory`!

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
```

```kotlin
preferenceScreen.forEach {
  if (it is PreferenceCategory) {
    it.children.forEach { child ->
      // TODO
    }
  } else {
    // TODO
  }
}
```